# How to send the "open menu" command to an application

Tags: buttons, menu, softkey

So, I have an application I'm trying to use, and on one phone, the buttons are soft-buttons on-screen, and on the other phone, the buttons are hardware buttons.

On the hardware button phone, when I launch the application, I don't see the triple dot to open the menu (The phone has the Box [hardware button] and Back Arrow).  On the software phone, there's the triple dot on the screen (Triangle, Circle, Box, Triple Dot).

I think my generic question is enough to answer the question, but here's the rest of the details if you're one not afraid to read the less relevant details:

The application I'm trying to use is: [KTSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koamtac.ktsync)

The phone with software buttons is: [Motorola Moto E](http://www.motorola.in/Moto-E/moto-e-in.html)

The phone with hardware buttons is: [Samsung Note 4](http://www.samsung.com/uk/discover/mobile/meet-the-samsung-galaxy-note-4/)

[image]    [image]

Edit: [Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord) suggested this, which works perfectly for devices you can access with ADB, but in my case I'm looking for how to do this without ADB:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can long hold the recents button on your device and that will open the menu.

---

In case you have root access and the above didn't work, you can still do it without using adb. Just open a terminal application and type this:

```
su
sleep 10; input keyevent 82
```

Switch to the other application within 10 seconds, and the menu should appear.